# Eclipse 4 persistency

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing an eclipse4 application.
I have some business object/model class (e.g.: employee class) to persist (on file).

What are the mechanisms provided by eclipse (4)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure, but eclipse plugins usually store data in properties file (xml or not)

Comment: Are you writing an Eclipse plugin, or is this a general question about serialising Java objects? You have used the Eclipse tag, but an employee class doesn't seem like the sort of thing a plugin would use.

Comment: Eclipse only really supports persistence for things like preferences and UI layout. Anything else would use some non-Eclipse mechanism.

Comment: Yes, i'am using E4. "Employee" class contains all the info about an employee (model) then I have an employee UI That shows the GUI. My question is ow to persist all the employee on a file? I'am pretty sure E4 offers something ...

Answer (score 0):

Not for 4, but 3.3, but comprehensive: [Eclipse and Java: Introducing Persistence](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/persistence.html) . The two basic things (not specific to Eclipse) that are used there are [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) and [`java.io.ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).